# How to change CSV file into 2 lists

Tags: python, csv, midi

I used this MIDI-CSV converter on a MIDI file and now I need to change the whole file into 2 lists so I can use them for my application. Basically, I need to take each pair of lines like this...

```
2, 960, Note_on_c, 0, 76, 71
2, 1200, Note_off_c, 0, 76, 0

2, 1200, Note_on_c, 0, 75, 38
2, 1440, Note_off_c, 0, 75, 0
```

and turn them into one item for each list.

```
NoteList=[56, 55]
NoteTypeList=['EthNote', 'EthNote']
```

If you're wondering why its 56 not 76 it's because I minus 20 to make the keyboard input 1-88 instead of 21-108 or whatever it is.

Comment: Please show what you have tried; there's _loads_ of similar questions, and documentation for the `csv` module. What did your research pull up?

Comment: I haven't tried anything I have no idea what to do. What should I try to search for, writing scripts?

Comment: Why not start [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)?